# Problems with variable expansion on Linux shell

Tags: shell, sh

I have a problem with the expansion of my variables in the next script:

```
fecha="$(date +'%d.%m.%Y')"
bkfile=$bkpath"backup_"$fecha".tar.gz"
tempfile="/tmp/Backup_"$fecha".tar.gz"
declare -a commandlist=(
'tar -pczf $tempfile /tmp/MyBackup/*'
'mv $tempfile $bkfile'
)
for command in "${commandlist[@]}"
do 
    echo $command
done
```

It´s shows me:

```
tar -pczf $tempfile /tmp/MyBackup/*
mv $tempfile $bkfile
```

and I need that the variable are expanded.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the single quote to double quote

```
'tar -pczf $tempfile /tmp/MyBackup/*'
'mv $tempfile $bkfile'
```

to

```
"tar -pczf $tempfile /tmp/MyBackup/*"
"mv $tempfile $bkfile"
```

Comment: The wildcard still won't be expanded if you attempt to run this as a command.  Fortunately, `tar` can simply accept `/tmp/MyBackup` as an argument. (See also [BashFAQ re: storing commands in variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), though.)